# Timestamp to Date Conversion in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to convert below Timestamp to Date?

The table has a column `created_date` with datatype `Timestamp(6)` and the sample value is `03-OCT-22 03.52.33.989000000 PM`

I need a query that will convert the Timestamp into `'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' Ex: 03-OCT-2022 03:52:33 PM`.

Please help me in writing this query.

Comment: '03:52:33 PM' is 'HH12:MI:SS AM', not 'HH24:MI:SS'... Are you actually talking about converting from timestamp to date *datatype*, or just formatting your timestamp for display without the fractional seconds (and maybe in 24-hour clock)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just *cast* it:

```
SQL> create table test (created_date timestamp(6));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (to_timestamp('03.10.2022 03:52:33.989000', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff6'));

1 row created.

SQL> select cast(created_date as date) result from test;

RESULT
-------------------
03.10.2022 03:52:33

SQL>
```

If you want to *reformat* it, apply `to_char` with desired format model, e.g.

```
SQL> select to_char(created_date, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh:mi:ss pm', 'nls_date_language = english') result
  2  from test;

RESULT
-----------------------
03-oct-2022 03:52:33 AM

SQL>
```